# Where to put jsp views for spring boot web application

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to use simple `jsp` and `bootstrap` for my view for spring-boot application.
Where my views should be in the classpath.

According to spring:
[image]

Shall the views go inside `template` folder even if I am not using `Thymeleaf`.

Comment: If you use JSPs you cannot use a jar, you have to use a war.

Comment: As @M.Deinum mentioned - if you are going to package as war then you use `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF...` else go for Thymeleaf and save then under `src/main/resources/templates`.

Comment: The fact that this never got an answer shows you it's complicated! I just started learning Spring and I too have no idea where to put the views even after reading all 1 billion pages on Google.